# A fairly easy rebus

Tags: rebus

Solve the following rebus puzzle
(which should be fairly easy for the users of this site):

```
   capP&Psule
```

Comment: I was rather expecting the answer to have something to do with the fact that the hint is in a code block as well as a quote block, since you said easy for *users of this site*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> (Two) Peas in a pod.

Reason:

> P&P = P's
>  Capsule = Pod

Comment: I'd rather see the rebus as cap2psule, but good job and fast response. I was trying to think of the ampersand.

Comment: Just a thought: I think the word being not aligned to left (or formattin overall) is another  clue. Given that asker's rep, (s)he would know how to format it if it wasn't related.

Comment: @goodguy5 Or even capppsule.

Answer (score 6):

**Note: This is certainly not the answer, I just spent too long thinking about it so I felt like posting it**

It bothered me that the hint was nested in a code block as well as a quote block but it was irrelevant to the answer, so I integrated it into mine.

**Answer:**

> Client Side TCP Three-Way Handshake Initiation
>  [Read More Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172983)

**Background:**

> The TCP Three-Way handshake is the way a client opens a connection with a server in the internet world. The client sends a SYN packet, the server acknowledges with an ACK, then the client sends a SYN-ACK, at which point the connection is complete.

**Reasoning:**

> **P&P** - The two packets the client will send out during this handshake, SYN and SYN-ACK 
> **capP&Psule** - The packets are *in* the word *capsule* - in order to send packets they must be *encapsulted* (in=en/capsule=capsulated)
> **Quote Block** - This process is sometimes called a *conversation* between the client and the server, the quote block denotes that this is what the client is saying in the conversation.
> **Code block** - The encapsulated packets are what the client is saying, the client is a computer, computers communicate in code. Hence, what is in the quote block must be put in a code block.